# WhiteListing IP Address in MongoDB in Production

Tags: mongodb, go, heroku

I am quite new to **MongoDB** and I noticed that before I can do any sort of connection with **MongoDB** I needed to whitelist my **IP Address**.

Now, whitelisting my **IP Address** for local deployment works

I am using **Go** to build a backend api that is to be hosted on **Heroku**.

My Question now is

When I deploy my app to **Heroku** how do I go about this **IP Address whitelisting** to make sure connections to my database are not stopped while in production?

Answer (score 2):

From the Heroku documentation [I need to whitelist Heroku dynos - what are IP address ranges in use at Heroku?](https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-whitelist-heroku-dynos-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku):

> Heroku Common Runtime Dynos use a subset of the IP range of the underlying AWS EC2 instances.

> The underlying AWS region for your app can be found as the provider.region field in the output of this CLI command:
>
> ```
> heroku regions --json
> ```
>
> The IPs in use by Heroku at any given time are highly dynamic, meaning that the published ranges may cover other IP addresses not currently in use by Heroku. This means that it is often not desirable to open up your firewall to the whole of the AWS region for security reasons. If you wanted to do this regardless you can find the published IP ranges from AWS here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

> For apps in the Common Runtime a better approach would be to use an add-on to provide a static outbound IP address https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/network or to rely on secure communication via TLS.

> For Private Spaces apps, these can use the static outbound IPs for your space. You can find details of these using these instructions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces#view-information-about-a-private-space